# altbeacon RSSI on different devices

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, altbeacon, ibeacon-android

I've done some experiments on different devices and I made each of the scanner and receiver at the same time and saved RSSI get from other nearby devices but the result was strange. first, there was a Huawei p6 that could scan other devices signal but nobody could see its transmit signal. second, the RSSI was completely device-dependent although beacons setting was the same for all of them inside the application and I want these signals to approximate their distance from each other.
question is that is this library reliable for my purpose which is getting approximately distance of devices from each other? I should mention that these results have gotten from android devices and I think that iPhones are another problem

Answer (score 0):

The fragmentation in Android devices means that there is a huge variation in not just bluetooth chips, but in the external bluetooth antennas and phone cases that affect the strength of the signal Android devices receive and transmit.

While the distance estimates provided by the Android Beacon Library are useful for finding the relative distances to different beacons, using the value as an absolute distance estimate will not be consistent across different Android devices.  The library does provide a way to [tune its distance estimates](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/distance-calculations.html) to a specific hardware model, but unless you are targeting only a small number of devices this approach is not practical to tune for thousands of Android models out there.

Comment: in my test i got rssi of -83 and -76 from two people that had 1 meter distance from me but got -64 from person who was in distance of 4 or 5 meters so it couldnt determine who was near and who was far

Comment: Presumably these were each different phone models, yes?  The -64 measurement at 4-5 meters is unusual.  This indicates either a very strong receiving antenna or more likely a bias on the measurement that overstates the signal strength on that device.